# How do I setup remote desktop to work seamlessly?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I've been using laptops for a very long time, and have preferred them over desktops for many reasons (one being, obviously, portability). However, right now I'm planning on building a simple home server that I can play with using one of those small form factor PCs in the market. I still want to take advantage of the mobility provided by laptops so I want to be able to remotely access this server I'm planning to build from any of my existent machines (a MacBook, and a Debian laptop). The question now is how (aside from `ssh`, etc.). I tried a VNC application on Ubuntu before (I forgot the name) but I didn't like how laggy it was; the overall experience wasn't very good. I'm really more interested in getting this work between the Debian laptop, and the new server (which will be a GNU/Linux machine as well). I will mostly be connecting these machines over local network, so no issues with Internet connections.

Comment: What kind of playing do you want to do? For individual applications you can just use `ssh -X` to the server and then start the application. But that obviously uses the desktop on your client machine and not the one on the server.

Comment: I'm going to be doing mostly software development (and deployment) on the new machine. I don't mind sitting on the desk from time to time but I'd also would like to be able to sort of take the environment with me to the other parts of the house through the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com) an elegant and useful remote desktop for Linux, Mac and Windows operating systems.